# VBA - autotype file password

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I have 2 excel workbooks: WB1 (password protected) and WB2.
WB2 takes some data from WB1. 
Everytime I open WB2 i need to type password to WB1 file. 
Is it possible to make VBA code that type password everytime I open wb2?

Comment: You would have to put it directly in the code. I assume your workbook is password protected for reason. Placing the password in another document that is not password protected would not be a best practice, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, and it's actually pretty easy! In workbook 2 you would add this code here to accomplish what you're looking for

```
Private Sub auto_open()
    Workbooks("workbook 1 name").Unprotect PASSWORD:="my password"
End Sub

Private Sub auto_close()
    Workbooks("workbook 1 name").Protect PASSWORD:="my password"
End Sub
```

I added the code to re-protect it once you close the second workbook but you might instead want it to be protected under other circumstances, so it's not exactly required.

You should also consider **only** having workbook 2 unprotect the first workbook during the time that it needs to pull data from workbook 1.

Comment: Suggestion, if you hardcode your password into the VBA program, I would suggest going to Tools > VBAProject Properties > Lock Project